# PostgreSQL: How to decrease time of query execution in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table which contains millions of records, but when i want to retrieve some rows its taking more time to process the query.

For example:
--Table

```
CREATE TABLE employee  
(  
empid int,  
empdate timestamp  
)
```

--Function to insert records

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insertemployee()  
RETURNS void AS  
$BODY$  
declare  
i int :=0;  
begin  
    while(i<100000)   
    loop   
    insert into employee values(i,now());  
    i:=i+1;  
    end loop;  
end;  
$BODY$  
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

--Function execution

```
select insertemployee();

Total query runtime: 891 ms.
```

--Function to retrieve the rows

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION retrieveemployee() RETURNS TABLE (empid int,empdate timestamp) AS  
$body$  
begin    
       return query    
       select e.empid,e.empdate from employee AS e WHERE e.empid BETWEEN 1000 and   80000;    
end;    
$body$    
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

--Function execution

```
select * from retrieveemployee();

Total query runtime: 1382 ms.
```

Comment: Your `insertemployee()` function can be replaced with a single insert statement: `insert into employee(empid, empdate) select i, now() from generate_series(1,100000) i`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not entirely clear what your problem is, but a generally good idea is to have a primary key on your table and indexes on any other columns that you regularly search on (a primary key is also an index, with the limitation that it is `UNIQUE`).

Indentally, rather than using `RETURNS TABLE` with a definition, you should have your function `RETURNS SETOF employee` to make things easier to understand and maintain.